# Stop animating container on second click

Tags: jquery, animation

Here the problem is which i click on main navigation link it animate the main content left, but i click the same link twice the content get disappear. Any one please help me on this:

here is the link http://mannatstudio.com/animation/

Here is the code i am using:

```
var tab, lasttab;
var defaultTab = '#profile-tab';
var direction = "rtl"; // Right To Left

$('.tab').hide();

function showTab(id) {
    id = id.replace("-tab", "");
    //window.location.hash = id;

    if (tab) {
        direction = (tab.attr('data-index') < $(id + "-tab").attr('data-index')) ? "rtl" : "ltr";
        lasttab = tab;
        lasttab.animate({
            'margin-left': (direction == "rtl") ? -0 - $(window).width() : -0 + $(window).width(),
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo", function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });

        if (tab.attr('id') == "team-tab") {
            $('#members-tab').animate({
                'margin-left': $(window).width(),
                opacity: 1
            }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo", function () {
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).unbind('click');
            });
        }
    }


    $('.nav').find('.current').removeClass('current');
    $('a[href="' + id + '"]').parent().addClass('current').prev().css('');

    tab = $(id + "-tab");
    tab.css({
        'margin-left': (direction == "rtl") ? -0 + $(window).width() : -0 - $(window).width(),
        opacity: 1
    }).show().animate({
        'margin-left': 0,
        opacity: 1,
    }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");

    if (id == "#team") {
        $('#members-tab').css({
            'margin-left': $(window).width()
        }).show().animate({
            'margin-left': 0
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo").find('.tab').show();

    }

    setFooterY();
}

function setFooterY() {
    var h = tab.height() + 150 + 0;

    if (tab.attr('id') == "team-tab") {
        $('#members-tab').height($('#members-tab').find('.page').height() + 0);
        h += $('#members-tab').height() - 0;
    }

    $('#content').height(h);
    $('#vignettage').height(0 + h);
}

if ($('.nav').length > 0 && $('#news-page').length == 0) {
    $('.nav').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        showTab($(e.target).attr('href'));

    });

    if (window.location.hash != "") {
        showTab(window.location.hash);
    } else {
        showTab(defaultTab);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(setFooterY, 500);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: http://mannatstudio.com/animation/ this is the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should check the `lasttab` and `tab` variable in the `showTab` function before animating anything in that.

Code as below for `showTab` check the changes marked with `//changed` in below.

```
function showTab(id) {
  id = id.replace("-tab", "");
  //window.location.hash = id;

  if (tab) {
    direction = (tab.attr('data-index') < $(id + "-tab").attr('data-index')) ? "rtl" : "ltr";
    lasttab = tab;
    lasttab.animate({
        'margin-left': (direction == "rtl") ? -0 - $(window).width() : -0 + $(window).width(),
        opacity: 1
    }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo", function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });

    if (tab.attr('id') == "team-tab") {
        $('#members-tab').animate({
            'margin-left': $(window).width(),
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo", function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).unbind('click');
        });
    }
  }


  $('.nav').find('.current').removeClass('current');
  $('a[href="' + id + '"]').parent().addClass('current').prev().css('');

  tab = $(id + "-tab");
  if (lasttab !== tab) { //changed
    tab.css({
     'margin-left': (direction == "rtl") ? -0 + $(window).width() : -0 - $(window).width(),
     opacity: 1
     }).show().animate({
     'margin-left': 0,
     opacity: 1,
    }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
  }

  if (id == "#team") {
    $('#members-tab').css({
        'margin-left': $(window).width()
    }).show().animate({
        'margin-left': 0
    }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo").find('.tab').show();

  }

  setFooterY();
}
```

BTW (By the way) check the jquery slider [here](http://www.slidesjs.com/) it is very good any you will get responsive slider with various browsers already tested. :D

### UPDATE

Check below the complete working example, apart from that the content height is not working for me defined in `setFooterY` function.

```
    var tab, lasttab;
var defaultTab = '#profile-tab';
var direction = "rtl"; // Right To Left

$('.tab').hide();

function showTab(id) {
    id = id.replace("-tab", "");
    //window.location.hash = id;

    if (tab) {
        direction = (tab.attr('data-index') < $(id + "-tab").attr('data-index')) ? "rtl" : "ltr";
        lasttab = tab;
        lasttab.animate({
            'margin-left': (direction == "rtl") ? -0 - $(window).width() : -0 + $(window).width(),
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo", function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });

        if (tab.attr('id') == "team-tab") {
            $('#members-tab').animate({
                'margin-left': $(window).width(),
                opacity: 1
            }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo", function () {
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).unbind('click');
            });
        }
    }


    $('.nav').find('.current').removeClass('current');
    $('a[href="' + id + '"]').parent().addClass('current').prev().css('');

    tab = $(id + "-tab");
    tab.css({
        'margin-left': (direction == "rtl") ? -0 + $(window).width() : -0 - $(window).width(),
        opacity: 1
    }).show().animate({
        'margin-left': 0,
        opacity: 1,
    }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");

    if (id == "#team") {
        $('#members-tab').css({
            'margin-left': $(window).width()
        }).show().animate({
            'margin-left': 0
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo").find('.tab').show();

    }

    setFooterY();
}

function setFooterY() {
    var h = tab.height() + 150 + 0;

    if (tab.attr('id') == "team-tab") {
        $('#members-tab').height($('#members-tab').find('.page').height() + 0);
        h += $('#members-tab').height() - 0;
    }

    $('#content').height(h);
    $('#vignettage').height(0 + h);
}

if ($('.nav').length > 0 && $('#news-page').length == 0) {
    $('.nav').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var clickedAnchor = $(e.target);
        if (!clickedAnchor.parent().hasClass('current')) {
            showTab(clickedAnchor.attr('href'));
        }

    });

    if (window.location.hash != "") {
        showTab(window.location.hash);
    } else {
        showTab(defaultTab);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(setFooterY, 500);
    });
}
```

Comment: Let me upload that for you.

Comment: http://mannatstudio.com/animation/ Please have a look here. Resize the browser to get for iphone resolution. If you do that one samlll menu will come to right of the browser. When you click menu it will toggle my menu. Just like the responsive design have a menu now a days. What i want is that when a user client on any link the content animate to the particular section, and also the menu get collapse. Let me know if you any query regarding this.

Comment: can you please ask separate question for this (as this is different than what is originally asked, so you would get more better responses from other developer like me) ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a verification on whether the div you wanna show is already visible and don't animate it:

```
...

if ($('.nav').length > 0 && $('#news-page').length == 0) {
    $('.nav').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       if(!$(''+$(e.target).attr('href')+'-tab').is(':visible')){
        showTab($(e.target).attr('href'));
       }

});

...
```

Comment: Can you give me full code for this. Better help doing so. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Use your code above,
Just add my snippet where you have the line:
'if ($('.nav').length > 0 && $('#news-page').length == 0) {
    $('.nav').on('click', 'a', function (e) {'..

I only added an 'if' condition to prevent triggering 'showTab' function IF the div that the anchor points to, is already visible

Comment: Modified answer, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your code that you assign `class="current"` to selected tab. You can disable `onclick` of current anchor using this class.

```
$('.current a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: mazhar:what is the problem?

Comment: Can u give me a full edited code. My current class is on li, so it not get worked